# React make navbar component with active class without react router (because of laravel routing)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-dom

I have a navigation component with custom routes. Now i want to make the 
link active when visiting a page. But i cant find the right solution 
because i am also using laravel. So what i need is to use react-router-dom with the react dom render method or something like that.

I am using the navigation in the header component and importing the header component in my pages.

Does someone have an idea how to fix this. Or what what direction i 
should look.

index.js

```
if(document.getElementById('home__page')) {
  ReactDOM.render(
  <Home />,
  document.getElementById('home__page')
);
```

nav.js

```
<nav>
  <ul><li>home</li></ul>
</nav>
```

I could make 10 different pages and add routing to each of them and then render them in my index file. But that doesn't sound great.

Comment: Are you using `react-router-dom` ?

Comment: Using Css solve it -    <style> a:active { background-color: yellow}  </style>

Comment: Hmm but my pages are written in react, how do i use react dom get element by id with react router dom? <router></router>

Comment: yes style is an option, thanks!  but i would need to use different id selectors to select the right link, i would prefer a props way.

Comment: Does someone know where to look for a solution or at least some docs?

Comment: Check this Link I share - https://codepen.io/k3no/pen/OXgXOb?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router-dom` includes a NavLink module which will render a `<a/>` element for you and has some built-in props you can use. For instance the `activeClassName` prop. This className will be applied to the element when the appropriate `Route` is active.

```
<NavLink to="/some-path" activeClassName="active">Link</NavLink>
```

When you define a `react-router-dom` Route to `"/some-path"` and this is the currently active path, the `"active"` className will be applied to the link element. You can use this className to change the styling for currently active links.

See the example here in the docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components/navigation

Comment: i am getting a Cannot read property 'location' of undefined error when using react router dom, i think because i am routing over laravel

Answer (score 0):

my solution is using jquery to manipulate dom elements after loading

```
    $(function () {
        const menuLink = location.pathname;
        if (menuLink === '/') {
            $('.menu a[href^="/"]').first().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.menu a[href^="/' + menuLink.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
        }
    });
```